# Angularjs directive link function

Tags: angularjs

html -

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="login-div">
        <div id="div1" class="login toggle">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
            <button class="btn-login">Login</button>
            <div class="link">
                <p id="p1" ng-click="toggleClick()">Click here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="sign-up toggle">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password
            <button class="btn-login">Sign up</button>" />
            <div class="link">
                <p id="p2" ng-click="toggleClick()">Click here again</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div3" class="sign-up toggle">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password
            <button class="btn-login">Sign up</button>" />
            <div class="link">
                <p id="p3" ng-click="toggleClick()">Click here again</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-close">
            <button>X</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

js file -

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  //$scope.toggleClick = function(){
  //  $rootScope.$broadcast("toogleDiv","");
  //};
});

myApp.directive('toggle', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           
            scope.toggleClick = function(){
              alert(element.attr('id'));
              element.slideToggle();
            };
        }                  
    }
});
```

irrespecitve of which ever paragraph item i click , the third div only toggles. However if you see the toggle directive is on all the divs . so basically all divs should slidetoggle but only the last one does.

style.css -

```css
.login-div{
    margin: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    position: relative;
}

.login, .sign-up {
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#EFF7F7;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}

.btn-close {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.btn-login{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

input{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    color: #555;
    width: 162px;
}

a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

link{
    text-align: right;
}



p{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `scope:{},` to directive definition should solve your problem. An isolated scope is required for your directive in order to reuse it.

The problem is that the `toggleClick` definition  gets assigned to the parent scope which based on your html means that `div3`'s execution of the directive overwrites and is the last function defined. Out of interest, if you swap your divs around, you'll probably notice that the last defined div will always be the that gets clicked.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/y5bD8yDZ0dLZZW6FlnFE

Comment: I tried the same with 1.4.8 version. It is not working.

Comment: @NagaSandeep - you may be correct as the compatibility issues with different versions of angular and jquery - https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq. The above question uses angular v1 and jquery 1.9

Comment: You are right. I didnt notice the version in OP. I was trying to achieve this in 1.4.8 :)

Comment: @NagaSandeep - updated pluker for v1.4 https://plnkr.co/edit/jcgSM5ydsqzaffbu1nFj?p=preview. The key here is the compile step